# EU Cookie Law can I use cookies before users' consent?

Tags: privacy, terms-of-service, european-union, consent

I am trying to get my website to be EU Cookie compliant and I have encountered some plugins which have something called "implied consent" in other words a popup appears on the website saying something like

> Cookies help us deliver our services. By using our services, you agree to our use of cookies.

along with two buttons: `"Read more"` and `"Got it"`. So my question is: Can I use cookies before the user has clicked on any of the buttons?

Comment: Related: [GDPR Compliance: Do all Cookies require Opt-In?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29083/gdpr-compliance-do-all-cookies-require-opt-in)

Answer (score 3):

The [ePrivacy directive](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:32002L0058:EN:HTML) (Article 5(3)) requires prior informed consent for storage (or access) of information stored on a user's terminal equipment.

In other words - **you must ask users** if they agree to most cookies and similar technologies **before the site starts to use them**.

That is not always technically possible or creates catastrophic UX, so take a close look at which cookies are exempt from consent according to the EU advisory body on data protection: [Opinion 04/2012 on Cookie Consent Exemption](https://iapp.org/media/pdf/resource_center/wp194_Cookie-Consent-Exemption_06-2012.pdf) ([original, dead link](http://ec.europa.eu/justice/data-protection/article-29/documentation/opinion-recommendation/files/2012/wp194_en.pdf)) (user‑input cookies (session-id), authentication cookies, user‑centric security cookies, multimedia content player cookies, user‑interface customisation cookies, third‑party social plug‑in content‑sharing cookies etc.).

**Update 2019:**  Europe’s top court says [active consent is needed for tracking cookies](https://techcrunch.com/2019/10/01/europes-top-court-says-active-consent-is-needed-for-tracking-cookies/). There are [few exemptions](https://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm) of cookies that generally do NOT require consent:

- User input cookies, for the duration of a session
- Authentication cookies, for the duration of a session
- User centric security cookies, used to detect authentication abuses and linked to the functionality explicitly requested by the user, for a limited persistent duration
- Multimedia content player session cookies, such as flash player cookies, for the duration of a session
- Load balancing session cookies, for the duration of session.
- User interface customisation cookies, for a browser session or a few hours, unless additional information in a prominent location is provided (e.g. “uses cookies” written next to the customisation feature