# GDPR Compliance: Do all Cookies require Opt-In?

Tags: gdpr, website

Given a Web Site which uses cookies for the following:

- User Preferences
- Bookmarked Articles
- Cookie Preferences

what explicit permissions would be required from the user?

Here I anticipate the cookies would be set from JavaScript, so no identification of the user would be required. I know that cookies are sent to the server.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not all cookies require consent.

The current answers are in [WP 29 Opinion 04/2012 on Cookie Consent Exemption - 00879/12/EN WP 194](https://ec.europa.eu/justice/article-29/documentation/opinion-recommendation/files/2012/wp194_en.pdf).

This WP29 Opinion is based upon Directive 2002/58/EC ("ePrivacy Directive"), and not GDPR, which is current law for this matter until other guidelines are adopted pursuant to GDPR or until the [awaited "ePrivacy Regulation"](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:52017PC0010) is finally adopted.

**1. General rules**

This Opinion states 2 critera for cookie consent exemption:

> (...) exempted from the requirement of informed consent, if they
> satisfy one of the following criteria:
>
> CRITERION A: the cookie is
> used “for the sole purpose of carrying out the transmission of a
> communication over an electronic communications network”.
>
> CRITERION B: the cookie is “strictly  necessary  in  order  for  the  provider
> of  an  information society service explicitly requested by the
> subscriber or user to provide the service”.

**2. User preferences**

The first two types of cookies would be, as I understand, for the purpose of remembering user preference in how it interacts with the Website. Such types of cookies can fall under criterion B, under certain conditions.

Section 3.6 "UI customization cookies" explains the conditions that such type of cookies have to meet so that the consent exemption can apply, in particular:

> User interface customization cookies are used to store a user’s
> preference regarding a service across web pages and **not linked to
> other persistent identifiers such as a username**. They are **only  set**
> **if  the  user  has explicitly  requested  the  service  to  remember**
> a  certain  piece  of information,  for  example,  by  clicking  on  a
> button  or  ticking  a  box.  They  may  be  **session cookies** **or** have a
> **lifespan counted in weeks or months, depending on their purpose**.

(...)

> These customization functionalities are thus explicitly  enabled by
> the user of an information society  service  (e.g.  by  clicking  on
> button  or  ticking  a  box)  although  **in  the  absence  of**
> **additional  information**  the  intention  of  the  user  could  not  be
> interpreted  as  a  preference  to remember  that  choice  for  longer
> than  a  **browser  session**  (or  no  more  than  a  few  additional
> hours).  As  such  **only  session  (or  short  term)  cookies**  storing
> such  information  **are  exempted** (...).  The  addition  of  additional
> information  in  a  prominent  location  (e.g. “uses  cookies”
> written  next  to  the  flag)  would  constitute  sufficient
> information  for  valid consent to remember the user’s preference for
> a longer duration, negating the requirement to apply an exemption in
> this case

If you need to request consent, then [WP 29 Working Document 02/2013
providing guidance on obtaining consent for cookies - 1676/13/EN WP 208](https://ec.europa.eu/justice/article-29/documentation/opinion-recommendation/files/2013/wp208_en.pdf) contains guidance.

**3. Cookie Preference cookie**

The last type of cookie you mention, being the Cookie Preference cookie, would be, as I understand, only used as a purely technical mean to store and retrieve (transmit) the user's explicit choices preferences, and would most probably fall clearly under criterion A and/or B.

Comment: Also, if the cookie does not contain information identifying a person it would not be subject to GDPR's privacy regulation. Example, if hotels.com leaves a cookie remembering search words then it would be ok to later present advertising based on those serach words.

Comment: This answer looks very promising. I am having trouble with the link on providing guidance on obtaining consent for cookies.. Is it this one: http://ec.europa.eu/justice/article-29/documentation/opinion-recommendation/files/2013/wp208_en.pdf ? Also, the documents predate the GDPR requirement — are they current?

Comment: @PerDigre, I disagree. The search words are linked to the user of the browser.

Comment: @Manngo, I fixed the link, sorry for that  These documents do pre-date the GDPR, and were adopted at the time the 95 Directive was in force, but the work done by G29 and their recommendations is not incompatible with the GDPR's provisions, and should apply today, until (and if) other guidelines are adopted.

Comment: @Manngo, GDPR is only about personal data. The cookies are linked to the browser, they do not necessarily know who the browser belongs to. You cannot ask for consent if you have no person to register the consent to. It is the same reason Google can present advertising based on searchwords from the session without asking consent. Also Hotels.com can present advertising based on previous searches (using domain cookies) without asking consent.

Comment: Tardis, both the opinion documents you are referring to specifies "personal" and "user" information. The first document mentions third party advertising as non-exempt, but it is my understanding that browsing-context when you are not logging to a specific user, does not fall under personal data. It is most definitely a point of argument the third party advertising will use for years to come.

Comment: @PerDigre, again, I disagree. The cookies allow the server to single-out a user, and yes, you can perfectly program your site to request consent before a cookie is set _when such consent is needed_. Whether you know the identity of the user of the browser or not is irrelevant: you are still processing data concerning the user's navigation in a way that allows to single-out that user, and that is a personal data processing. Depending on the purpose of the collection and the type of cookie, consent will be required or not, and that is when WP29 Opinion on Cookie Consent Exemption is useful.

Comment: @Tardis we are allowed to disagree ;-)  You have very insightful information and you may be right. For the time being I don't think we have a definite answer. Blogs and websites hash on the question of what is considered personal data. GDPR clearly states person-identifying data. Example of one company's point of view, https://www.cookiebot.com/en/gdpr-cookies/?gclid=CjwKCAjwr-PYBRB8EiwALtjbz1b0fzIP-f7aS48RcTUMh0Rf2UHKViRDKT7yWSzfb3lwI-pHxwVUtBoC19EQAvD_BwE

Comment: @PerDigre, sure we can ;-) Indeed, matter is complex since e-Privacy Directive is _lex specialis_ of the defunct 95 Directive on data protection. But the e-Privacy Directive and the coming e-Privacy Regulation are meant to protect _privacy_, and not only personal data. See: https://www.privacytrust.com/guidance/gdpr-vs-eprivacy-regulation.html Personally, until e-Privacy Regulation is adopted and other guidelines for cookies are issued, I would follow the mentioned WP29's Opinion. After all, it is the opinion of the data protection authorities of the EU about the e-Privacy Directive :-)