# GDPR: cookie for login management

Tags: gdpr

I use cookie in my site for login management.
I user logs in the cookie dies with the session, if user flags "Keep me logged in" when logging in a long time cookie persists.
In the long time cookie I store a hashed informations (user_id,password_hash). It's used to check if user is still logged in in a new session and I use these informations to check if user can access site without relogin.
I read in some article about GDPR that technical cookies are allowed without any disclaimer.
I can consider my login cookie a technical cookie since I store only these informations?
Do I need to show the disclaimer in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [WP 29 Opinion 04/2012 on Cookie Consent Exemption - 00879/12/EN WP 194](https://ec.europa.eu/justice/article-29/documentation/opinion-recommendation/files/2012/wp194_en.pdf):

> Persistent  login  cookies  which  store  an  authentication  token 
>   across  browser  sessions  are  not  exempted under CRITERION B. This
>   is an important distinction because the user may not be  immediately 
>   aware  of  the  fact  that  closing  the  browser  will  not  clear 
>   their  authentication  settings. They may return to the website under
>   the assumption that they are anonymous whilst  in fact they are still
>   logged in to the service. The commonly seen method of using a
>   checkbox  and a simple information note such as “remember me (uses
>   cookies)” next to the submit form  would  be  an  appropriate  means 
>   of  gaining  consent  therefore  negating  the  need  to  apply  an 
>   exemption in this case.

So a cookie to keep a user logged in, requires consent. But the checkbox "Keep me logged in" is appropriate to gain consent. So in your case you do not need to display a cookie banner.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/29084/18215) for more details about other kinds of cookies which don't require consent.

Comment: So it's enough the string "Keep me logged in" or i must write "Keep me logged in (this uses cookies)" ?

Comment: The WP29 text includes "uses cookies", as they are the experts, it is probably better to do that.